# Existential type at declaration site

Tags: scala, existential-type

I was playing around with Scala when I found that this compiles:

```
class Foo[_]
```

What does an existential type in a class declaration do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is legal because of following part of the grammar (given in the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)):

```
TmplDef ::= ‘class’ ClassDef
ClassDef ::= id [TypeParamClause] {Annotation}
  [AccessModifier] ClassParamClauses ClassTemplateOpt
TypeParamClause ::= ‘[’ VariantTypeParam {‘,’ VariantTypeParam} ‘]’
VariantTypeParam ::= {Annotation} [‘+’ | ‘-’] TypeParam
TypeParam ::= (id | ‘_’) [TypeParamClause] [‘>:’ Type] [‘<:’ Type] [‘:’ Type]
```

I believe `_` simply ends up being a type parameter name (which isn't actually usable in the class body), not part of existential type syntax.

Comment: You are correct, that underscore is not used by existentials. But I must be blind, because I cannot find where the underscore syntax for existentials is defined in the spec at all.

Comment: @drhagen Page 27, "Placeholder Syntax for Existential Types"

Comment: Sorry, I saw that, but I don't see where a `WildcardType` is referenced in any other syntax, which would indicate where a wildcard existential is legal.

Comment: @drhagen "A wildcard type must appear as type argument of a parameterized type... Wildcard types may also appear as parts of infix types (§3.2.8), function types (§3.2.9), or tuple types (§3.2.5). Their expansion is then the expansion in the equivalent parameterized type." Though I agree it doesn't make much sense to define `WildcardType` non-terminal and not reference it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure but it appears it is equivalent to:

```
scala> class Foo[T >: Nothing <: AnyRef]
defined class Foo
```

Just that you cannot have access to `T`. This can be confirmed by checking compilation with `-Xprint:all`. They both generate same AST.

Playing around:

```
scala> new Foo
res3: Foo[Nothing] = Foo@de0a01f

scala> new Foo[String]
res4: Foo[String] = Foo@47fd17e3

scala> class Foo2[_]
defined class Foo2

scala> new Foo2[String]
res5: Foo2[String] = Foo2@2d6e8792
```

Comment: Is there a reason to have a type parameter that cannot be accessed? I mean, Scala will not let me have a regular parameter that cannot be accessed like `def foo(_:Int):Unit = () //error`.

Comment: The place it's useful is in higher-kinded types: `Functor[F[_]]` (`Functor[F[X]]` is equivalent, but I think the first is clearer, since the name is irrelevant). The grammar could distinguish top-level and nested TypeParamClause, of course.